# Idea considers variables initialized in Promise.all() as not initialized

Tags: javascript

Is there any bug in my code? Or is Idea wrong?

```
  let pollVotesCount, commentVotesCount, sharesCount, commentsCount, blogCount;

  const pollVotesPromise = getPollVoteCount(dbClient, userId);
  const commentVotesPromise = getCommentVotesCount(dbClient, userId);
  const sharesPromise = getShareLinkCount(dbClient, userId);
  const commentsPromise = getCommentedCount(dbClient, userId);
  const blogPromise = getBlogCount(dbClient, userId);
  Promise.all([pollVotesPromise, commentVotesPromise, sharesPromise, commentsPromise, blogPromise]).then((values) => {
    pollVotesCount = values[0];
    commentVotesCount = values[1];
    sharesCount = values[2];
    commentsCount = values[3];
    blogCount = values[4];
  });

 // Idea complains that these variables can be uninitialized
 if (pollVotesCount >= 1 && commentVotesCount >= 1 && sharesCount >= 1 && commentsCount >= 1) {
      finalRank = 'student';
 }
```

My understanding is that either `then()` will be called or exception will interrupt the execution.

Update: added loop to provide an context

```
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
  user = users[i];
  const currentRank = (user.honors) ? user.honors.rank : '';
  const userId = user._id;
  let finalRank = 'novice';
  let pollVotesCount, commentVotesCount, sharesCount, commentsCount, blogCount;

  const pollVotesPromise = getPollVoteCount(dbClient, userId);
  const commentVotesPromise = getCommentVotesCount(dbClient, userId);
  const sharesPromise = getShareLinkCount(dbClient, userId);
  const commentsPromise = getCommentedCount(dbClient, userId);
  const blogPromise = getBlogCount(dbClient, userId);
  Promise.all([pollVotesPromise, commentVotesPromise, sharesPromise, commentsPromise, blogPromise]).then(async (values) => {
    pollVotesCount = values[0];
    commentVotesCount = values[1];
    sharesCount = values[2];
    commentsCount = values[3];
    blogCount = values[4];

    if (!currentRank || currentRank === 'novice') {
      if (pollVotesCount >= 1 && commentVotesCount >= 1 && sharesCount >= 1 && commentsCount >= 1) {
        finalRank = 'student';
      }
    } else if (currentRank === 'student') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      const positiveCommentsVotesCount = await getPositiveCommentsVotesCount(dbClient, userId);
      if (pollVotesCount >= 3 && sharesCount >= 10 && positiveCommentsVotesCount >= 5 && blogCount >= 1) {
        finalRank = 'graduate';
      }
    } else if (currentRank === 'graduate') {
      const positivePercent = await getPositivePercent(dbClient, userId);
      const consecutiveSharing = await getConsecutiveSharing(dbClient, userId, 10);
      if (pollVotesCount >= 10 && consecutiveSharing && positivePercent >= 80 && commentsCount >= 100 && blogCount >= 10) {
        finalRank = 'master';
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }

    const setters = {
      'honors.count.poll_votes': pollVotesCount,
      'honors.count.comment_votes': commentVotesCount,
      'honors.count.comment': commentsCount,
      'honors.count.blog': blogCount,
      'honors.count.shares': sharesCount,
    };
    if (currentRank !== finalRank) {
      setters['honors.rank'] = finalRank;
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await dbClient.db().collection('users').updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $set: setters });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `if()` needs to be inside the `then()`. You are doing the comparison before all the promises resolve

Comment: The primary issue I see is that you are evaluating the results in your `if` block at the bottom before the values have been assigned in the callback to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Merely calling `Promise.all` does not cause the currently executing block of code to wait for all of those promises to execute before continuing. Asynchronous code never works that way - otherwise why would you even need to use `.then()` and provide a whole other function? You *must* put code that depends on the results of those promises *inside* of the `.then()` callback.

Comment: I see. But it is not such easy to resolve because this code is run within a loop. How can I make sure it is executed?

Comment: Depends how the loop needs to work. Not enough known from what is shown

Comment: Added complete context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly pust your `if` inside `then` and instead of assignig, you can destructure values this way.**

```
const pollVotesPromise = getPollVoteCount(dbClient, userId);
const commentVotesPromise = getCommentVotesCount(dbClient, userId);
const sharesPromise = getShareLinkCount(dbClient, userId);
const commentsPromise = getCommentedCount(dbClient, userId);
const blogPromise = getBlogCount(dbClient, userId);
Promise.all([pollVotesPromise, commentVotesPromise, sharesPromise, commentsPromise, blogPromise]).then([
  pollVotesCount,
  commentVotesCount,
  sharesCount,
  commentsCount,
  blogCount
] => {
  if (pollVotesCount >= 1 && commentVotesCount >= 1 && sharesCount >= 1 && commentsCount >= 1) {
    finalRank = 'student';
  }
});
```

For updated question:

**make your function which wraps `for loop` an `async` like below**

```js
async someFunc() { ...for loop... }
```

then

```js
const [pollVotesCount,commentVotesCount,sharesCount,commentsCount,blogCount] = 
    await Promise.all([pollVotesPromise, commentVotesPromise, sharesPromise, commentsPromise, blogPromise])
if (!currentRank || currentRank === 'novice') { // continue your code from here ("then" not needed)
```

Comment: The `let` at top is now redundant

Comment: Thank you for destructure explanation. I have updated my question with the context. This code is executed in a loop. I worry that the loop will not await this Promise.all().